# Xamarin OpenCV Imageproc.FindContours

Tags: android, opencv, xamarin

I'm trying to find contours on the stream from camera using **OpenCv**. So far I had no success. I tried with **Canny()** and with **Threshold()** approach but in both cases **FindContours()** returned 0 contours.

I searched everywhere if someone had similar issue, but none of described solutions worked for me.

Does anyone knows what could be an issue. If required I can attach code later, but I doubt that it could reveal something, but if required, I'll do anything to get some help.

Comment: I have the same problem. Tried different ways and don't know how to resolve it..